# Getting Status : 415 while making POST Request using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to make `POST` request using fetch. I am actually following docs example. Docs Provided `curl` example to make `POST` request

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/upload/01
 -d "api_key=948324jkl3h45h"
 -d "@path/filename.mp4"
 -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

There is `.mp4` file in my dir. I wrote a simple script to make `POST` request using fetch. Here is my code.

```
const filePath = path.join(__dirname , "/video/video.mp4");
const fileData = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
fetch(url, {
        body: `api_key=${API_KEY}&${fileData}`,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        method: "POST"
      }).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
      })
```

When I make `POST` request I am getting this error.

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https:/example.com/upload/01',
    status: 415,
    statusText: 'Unsupported Media Type',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

I read file using `fs.createReadStream`. Is that actually right? If there is something wrong, please point me out. I thought some of my file system getting wrong while reading `mp4`. I wish someone can help me.

Thank youu.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not allow for file uploads, and `fs.createReamStream` indeed does sound wrong. You need multipart/form-data support and libraries that can handle this

Comment: [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) returns a response which you then need to convert to the correct data type. So instead of logging you need to do `result.json()` or [one of the other methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_methods) depending on your needs.